# CGDataProvider returning null in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, image, memory-management, swift4

I'm trying to fix a problem in SwiftColorPicker (by Matthias Schlemm) that popped up with Swift 4.0. I'm going to include the whole PickerImage class, so you can see the full context.

```
import UIKit
import ImageIO

open class PickerImage {
    var provider:CGDataProvider!
    var imageSource:CGImageSource?
    var image:UIImage?
    var mutableData:CFMutableData
    var width:Int
    var height:Int

    fileprivate func createImageFromData(_ width:Int, height:Int) {
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue)
        let provider = CGDataProvider(data: mutableData)
        imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithDataProvider(provider!, nil)
        let cgimg = CGImage(width: Int(width), height: Int(height), bitsPerComponent: Int(8), bitsPerPixel: Int(32), bytesPerRow: Int(width) * Int(4),
                            space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo, provider: provider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent)
        image = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg!)
    }

    func changeSize(_ width:Int, height:Int) {
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        let size:Int = width * height * 4
        CFDataSetLength(mutableData, size)
        createImageFromData(width, height: height)
    }

    init(width:Int, height:Int) {
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        let size:Int = width * height * 4
        mutableData = CFDataCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, size)
        createImageFromData(width, height: height)
    }

    open func writeColorData(_ h:CGFloat, a:CGFloat) {

        let d = CFDataGetMutableBytePtr(self.mutableData)

        if width == 0 || height == 0 {
            return
        }

        var i:Int = 0
        let h360:CGFloat = ((h == 1 ? 0 : h) * 360) / 60.0
        let sector:Int = Int(floor(h360))
        let f:CGFloat = h360 - CGFloat(sector)
        let f1:CGFloat = 1.0 - f
        var p:CGFloat = 0.0
        var q:CGFloat = 0.0
        var t:CGFloat = 0.0
        let sd:CGFloat = 1.0 / CGFloat(width)
        let vd:CGFloat =  1 / CGFloat(height)

        var double_s:CGFloat = 0
        var pf:CGFloat = 0
        let v_range = 0..<height
        let s_range = 0..<width

        for v in v_range {
            pf = 255 * CGFloat(v) * vd
            for s in s_range {
                i = (v * width + s) * 4
                d?[i] = UInt8(255)
                if s == 0 {
                    q = pf
                    d?[i+1] = UInt8(q)
                    d?[i+2] = UInt8(q)
                    d?[i+3] = UInt8(q)
                    continue
                }

                double_s = CGFloat(s) * sd
                p = pf * (1.0 - double_s)
                q = pf * (1.0 - double_s * f)
                t = pf * ( 1.0 - double_s  * f1)
                switch(sector) {
                case 0:
                    d?[i+1] = UInt8(pf)
                    d?[i+2] = UInt8(t)
                    d?[i+3] = UInt8(p)
                case 1:
                    d?[i+1] = UInt8(q)
                    d?[i+2] = UInt8(pf)
                    d?[i+3] = UInt8(p)
                case 2:
                    d?[i+1] = UInt8(p)
                    d?[i+2] = UInt8(pf)
                    d?[i+3] = UInt8(t)
                case 3:
                    d?[i+1] = UInt8(p)
                    d?[i+2] = UInt8(q)
                    d?[i+3] = UInt8(pf)
                case 4:
                    d?[i+1] = UInt8(t)
                    d?[i+2] = UInt8(p)
                    d?[i+3] = UInt8(pf)
                default:
                    d?[i+1] = UInt8(pf)
                    d?[i+2] = UInt8(p)
                    d?[i+3] = UInt8(q)
                }


            }
        }
    }


}
```

In `createImageFromData`, the line

```
let provider = CGDataProvider(data: mutableData)
```

is returning a nil value, which, of course, causes the following line to crash. This was working fine in Swift 3.

Here are the values in debugger:

[image]

Dealing with memory allocation is a bit beyond my current skillset, so I'm struggling with what's actually going on here. Has anything related to this changed in Swift 4.0 that would cause the `CGDataProvider` call to return a nil value?

Edit:
Here is the ColorPicker class that initializes the PickerImage objects.

```
import UIKit
import ImageIO

open class ColorPicker: UIView {

    fileprivate var pickerImage1:PickerImage?
    fileprivate var pickerImage2:PickerImage?
    fileprivate var image:UIImage?
    fileprivate var data1Shown = false
    fileprivate lazy var opQueue:OperationQueue = {return OperationQueue()}()
    fileprivate var lock:NSLock = NSLock()
    fileprivate var rerender = false
    open var onColorChange:((_ color:UIColor, _ finished:Bool)->Void)? = nil


    open var a:CGFloat = 1 {
        didSet {
            if a < 0 || a > 1 {
                a = max(0, min(1, a))
            }
        }
    }

    open var h:CGFloat = 0 { // // [0,1]
        didSet {
            if h > 1 || h < 0 {
                h = max(0, min(1, h))
            }
            renderBitmap()
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }

    }
    fileprivate var currentPoint:CGPoint = CGPoint.zero


    open func saturationFromCurrentPoint() -> CGFloat {
        return (1 / bounds.width) * currentPoint.x
    }

    open func brigthnessFromCurrentPoint() -> CGFloat {
        return (1 / bounds.height) * currentPoint.y
    }

    open var color:UIColor  {
        set(value) {
            var hue:CGFloat = 1
            var saturation:CGFloat = 1
            var brightness:CGFloat = 1
            var alpha:CGFloat = 1
            value.getHue(&hue, saturation: &saturation, brightness: &brightness, alpha: &alpha)
            a = alpha
            if hue != h || pickerImage1 === nil {
                self.h = hue
            }
            currentPoint = CGPoint(x: saturation * bounds.width, y: brightness * bounds.height)
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
        get {
            return UIColor(hue: h, saturation: saturationFromCurrentPoint(), brightness: brigthnessFromCurrentPoint(), alpha: a)
        }
    }

    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        clipsToBounds = false
        self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "bounds", options: [NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, NSKeyValueObservingOptions.initial], context: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        self.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "bounds")
    }

    open override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if keyPath == "bounds" {
            if let pImage1 = pickerImage1 {
                pImage1.changeSize(Int(self.bounds.width), height: Int(self.bounds.height))
            }
            if let pImage2 = pickerImage2 {
                pImage2.changeSize(Int(self.bounds.width), height: Int(self.bounds.height))
            }
            renderBitmap()
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        } else {
            super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
        }
    }

    open override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first! as UITouch
        handleTouche(touch, ended: false)
    }

    open override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first! as UITouch
        handleTouche(touch, ended: false)
    }

    open override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first! as UITouch
        handleTouche(touch, ended: true)
    }

    fileprivate func handleColorChange(_ color:UIColor, changing:Bool) {
        if color !== self.color {
            if let handler = onColorChange {
                handler(color, !changing)
            }
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    fileprivate func handleTouche(_ touch:UITouch, ended:Bool) {
        // set current point
        let point = touch.location(in: self)
        if self.bounds.contains(point) {
            currentPoint = point
        } else {
            let x:CGFloat = min(bounds.width, max(0, point.x))
            let y:CGFloat = min(bounds.width, max(0, point.y))
            currentPoint = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
        }
        handleColorChange(pointToColor(point), changing: !ended)
    }

    fileprivate func pointToColor(_ point:CGPoint) ->UIColor {
        let s:CGFloat = min(1, max(0, (1.0 / bounds.width) * point.x))
        let b:CGFloat = min(1, max(0, (1.0 / bounds.height) * point.y))
        return UIColor(hue: h, saturation: s, brightness: b, alpha:a)
    }

    fileprivate func renderBitmap() {
        if self.bounds.isEmpty {
            return
        }
        if !lock.try() {
            rerender = true
            return
        }
        rerender = false

        if pickerImage1 == nil {
            self.pickerImage1 = PickerImage(width: Int(bounds.width), height: Int(bounds.height))
            self.pickerImage2 = PickerImage(width: Int(bounds.width), height: Int(bounds.height))
        }

        opQueue.addOperation { () -> Void in
            // Write colors to data array
            if self.data1Shown { self.pickerImage2!.writeColorData(self.h, a:self.a) }
            else { self.pickerImage1!.writeColorData(self.h, a:self.a)}


            // flip images
//            self.image = self.data1Shown ? self.pickerImage2!.image! : self.pickerImage1!.image!
            self.data1Shown = !self.data1Shown

            // make changes visible
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({ () -> Void in
                self.setNeedsDisplay()
                self.lock.unlock()
                if self.rerender {
                    self.renderBitmap()
                }
            })

        }

    }



    open override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        if let img = image {
            img.draw(in: rect)
        }

        //// Oval Drawing
        let ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: currentPoint.x - 5, y: currentPoint.y - 5, width: 10, height: 10))
        UIColor.white.setStroke()
        ovalPath.lineWidth = 1
        ovalPath.stroke()

        //// Oval 2 Drawing
        let oval2Path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: currentPoint.x - 4, y: currentPoint.y - 4, width: 8, height: 8))
        UIColor.black.setStroke()
        oval2Path.lineWidth = 1
        oval2Path.stroke()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a problem of Swift 4, but a problem of iOS 11. You may find your code *works* on iOS 10 simulator.

The original code seemingly works in iOS 10, depending on just a luck.

In this part of the code:

```
init(width:Int, height:Int) {
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    let size:Int = width * height * 4
    mutableData = CFDataCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, size)
    createImageFromData(width, height: height)
}
```

The property `mutableData` is initialized with a `CFMutableData` of capacity: `size`, and [*empty (that is, content-less)*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1542051-cfdatacreatemutable).

And in iOS 11, the initializer `CGDataProvider.init(data:)` rejects an empty `CFData` as it should not be empty as a data provider.

A quick fix would be something like this:

```
init(width:Int, height:Int) {
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    let size:Int = width * height * 4
    mutableData = CFDataCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, size)
    CFDataSetLength(mutableData, size) //<-set the length of the data
    createImageFromData(width, height: height)
}
```

But I'm not sure other parts of the code would work as expected in iOS 11.

Comment: That's it! Setting the length of the data fixes it... even when deployed as iOS 11 (for my purposes, anyways). Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you added `let` to that line and it creates a new variable call `provider` within the function `createImageFromData`. That way, it's never passed to the `provider` parameter of the class and then, it's always null. Just remove the `let` and it should work properly.

```
fileprivate func createImageFromData(_ width:Int, height:Int) {
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue)
    provider = CGDataProvider(data: mutableData)
    imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithDataProvider(provider!, nil)
    let cgimg = CGImage(width: Int(width), height: Int(height), bitsPerComponent: Int(8), bitsPerPixel: Int(32), bytesPerRow: Int(width) * Int(4),
                        space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo, provider: provider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent)
    image = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg!)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I completely missed that. However, I'm still getting the `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` error on the `imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithDataProvider(provider!, nil)` and provider is still null.

Comment: It's working for me. What values are you giving to the `ImagePicker` class when it's created?

Comment: PickerImage is initialized with width: 240 height: 128

Comment: I edited my question and added the calling class, in case that helps. All source is available at https://github.com/MrMatthias/SwiftColorPicker

Comment: Can I see the new code you changed? It's working on my computer. It's impossible provider not being initialized now.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm guessing you were running it in iOS 10 and I was at iOS 11. Anyways, setting the length of the mutableData fixed it.